# What is the proper way to use export_savedmodel in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I am working with Tensorflow 1.8.

I created a custom tf.estimator `my_estimator`, and after training I want to export my model in order to use it after for prediction. To do so, I tried (`feature_placeholders` are the inputs of my model):

```
feature_placeholders = {
        "Numerical_features": tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, parameters.model_params['N_INPUT']]),
        "Categorical_features": tf.placeholder(tf.int32,
                                               [None, None, len(parameters.model_params['vocabulary_sizes'].keys())]),
        "Fixed_features": tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None]),
        "Lengths_features": tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None]),
        "labels": tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None]),
        "Predictions": tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
                                }

my_estimator.export_savedmodel('my_directory',
        serving_input_receiver_fn=tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(
        features=feature_placeholders)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
 File "/home/train_eval_predict.py", line 650, in train_rnn
    features=feature_placeholders)
  File "/home/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 613, in export_savedmodel
    config=self.config)
  File "/home/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 831, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/train_eval_predict.py", line 418, in model_fn
    logits=prediction))
  File "/home/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1829, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2
    logits)
  File "/home/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1777, in _ensure_xent_args
    raise ValueError("Both labels and logits must be provided.")
ValueError: Both labels and logits must be provided.
```

How can I fix this ?

By the way, I'm not sure `feature_placeholders` is properly defined with respect to `tf.estimator.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn()`.